# Aggregate functions on complete result instead on groups

Tags: sql

Is there another way beside a sub-select to get the result of an aggregate function based on the result of the whole query rather than each group?

Example:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY objId;
```

Returns the count of entries for each `objId`.

One way to get the number of different `objId`s is to nest the queries:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM 
     (SELECT objId 
      FROM table 
      GROUP BY objId);
```

But is there another way to specify the working scope of the `count` function without the sub query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query is more easily handled using `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct objid)
from table;
```

Note:  there is a subtle difference if `objid` could be `NULL`.  If so, then the correct replacement is:

```
select (count(distinct objid) +
        max(case when objid is null then 1 else 0 end)
       )
from table;
```